# How to use Firebase notification to notify to a user that a value changed Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

For example, in a chat messaging app how can I send a notification to the other user in the chat that the user replied?

Will I need to set up another server or can all this get done within firebase?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging). Check there for the complete information.

Comment: This is the correct approach. OP, please note that you'll have to develop a server app to send notifications.

Answer (score 0):

From the onMessageReceived method of FirebaseMessagingService you can Broadcast that message or notification with the help of the LocalBroadcastManager and can handle that broadcast in your ChatActivity and append the user reply in your chatlistview or you can generate a notification with the help of the Notification builder.

Here is a good tutorial from where you can learn this functionality easily..
(Tutorial is not related to FCM).

[Link to Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-3/)